# Simulate WiFi Stations for testing the AP

Tags: wireless, wifi

I was thinking if I can simulate WiFi stations(around 5 numbers) in my laptop, that I can try associating these stations to my AP and load test the AP. Could some one suggest on this or is there any alternative way other than procuring real hardware WiFi stations?

Comment: Load test how? Associate as a client to your AP?

Comment: @Passerby, I would like to connect 4 to 5 stations to the AP and start traffic and I need to test the AP(which is my org's product) and its performance on multiple devices etc..

Comment: Use 5 old smartphones.

Comment: By station you mean clients? A typical computer software stack for a wifi card only allows for a single connection as a client, maybe two (wifi repeater mode essentially halving or worse the bandwidth). To maximize the connection you would want individual clients anyway. Cheap you can get a bunch of old laptops or a few raspberry pi.

Comment: @Passerby "station" is IEEE802.11 lingo for client :)

Answer (score 1):

@Passerby is right, you can't test the interesting things about having multiple stations with a single Wifi device:

- max total load would be the same as if a single station was trying to max out data transfer
- Can't have different qualities of channels (and even less independent MIMO channel realizations) with a single antenna (or a single set of antennas)
- Can't test how collisions are handled

What you can test with a single card is how the AP and infrastructure behind handles very many concurrent connections, i.e. how well it handles user state in memory. But then we're talking 50 or 500 stations per AP, not 5; but yeah, that's pretty simple to do: for most Wifi adapters these days, the user data handling is done in host software, so "all" you need to do is set your single adapter into promiscous mode, tell your WPA supplicant that's the case, ask it to provision for the appropriate number of connections, and craft the appropriate association packets.

By the way, you can basically plug as many USB Wifi adapters into your laptop as you've got USB bandwidth. And any OS I worked with (Linux, BSDs) supports practically unlimited number of network adapters and thus wifi connections out of the box, so there's a simple, and relatively cheap solution: Buy a USB3 hub, buy a couple of Wifi dongles, and go wild.